# How to append HTML div with jquery and bootstrap col, row classes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have some problems with .append and now I am not quite sure how exactly this function is working. Now I have the following html:

```
<?php echo CHtml::hiddenField('counter_row', '2') ?>
<div class="timeslots_from_to row top20">
    <div class="row">
        <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">От</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" class="timepickerfrom" id="from1">
        </div>
        <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">До</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" class="timepickerto" id="to1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-circle add-row"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="insideContainer"></div>
    <h5 id="error_msg"></h5>
</div>
```

This is one row with two labels, two timepickers and button for adding more rows. When the button **add-row** is clicked, this script is executing:

```
$(document).on("click", ".add-row", function () {
        var i = $('#counter_row').val();
        console.log('counter_row ' + i);
        $("#error_msg").html("");

        if($('#from'+(i-1)).val() >= $('#to'+(i-1)).val()) {
            $("#error_msg").html("Грешка");
          return false;
        } 
        
        $("<div />", { "class":"row" })
            .append("<div class='col-md-1>")
            .append("<label> От </label>")
            .append("</div>")
            .append("<div class='col-md-1>")
            .append($("<input />", { type: "text", id:"from"+i, class:"timepickerfrom" }))
            .append("</div>")
            .append("<div class='col-md-1>")
            .append("<label> До </label>")
            .append("</div>")
            .append("<div class='col-md-4>")
            .append($("<input />", { type: "text", id:"to"+i, class:"timepickerto" }))
            .append("</div>")
            .appendTo("#insideContainer");

        $('#from'+i).val($('#to' + (i-1)).val());   

        i++;
        $('#counter_row').val(i);

        $('input.timepickerfrom').timepicker({
            timeFormat: 'H:mm',
            interval: 15,
            minTime: '8',
            maxTime: '22:15',
            startTime: '08:00',
            dynamic: false,
            dropdown: true,
            scrollbar: true
        });
        $('input.timepickerto').timepicker({
            timeFormat: 'H:mm',
            interval: 15,
            minTime: '08:15',
            maxTime: '22:30',
            startTime: '08:15',
            dynamic: false,
            dropdown: true,
            scrollbar: true
        });
    });
```

But unfortunately is does not return the desire result. I want to add rows like the first which is already in the html part (without the button), but it looks like this:
[image: current result]

Do you know what I am doing wrong and why this script does not append with bootstrap classes included?

To make it clear, I will also attach how does the return code looks in inspect of the browser page:
[image: elements]

I will be glad if you notice what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Not exactly how $.append works. Build your columns before using append. Notice that the incomplete elements you're trying to attach are not being included.

Comment: Which elements are incomplete? I am not quite sure that I get what I should do. Do you tell me that I have to make one variable with sequence of html and then append it as a whole?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build each column individually, then append them to the row:

```js
const $labelCol1 = $('<div class="col-md-1"></div>').append('<label> От </label>')
const $labelCol2 = $('<div class="col-md-1"></div>').append('<label> До </label>')
const $inputCol1 = $('<div class="col-md-4"></div>').append($("<input />", { type: "text", id:"from"+i, class:"timepickerfrom" }))
const $inputCol2 = $('<div class="col-md-4"></div>').append($("<input />", { type: "text", id:"to"+i, class:"timepickerto" }))

$('<div class="row"></div>')
   .append($labelCol1)
   .append($inputCol1)
   .append($labelCol2)
   .append($inputCol2)
   // Because of the missing button you're 2 columns short. Add a placeholder.
   .append('<div class="col-md-2" />')
   .appendTo("#insideContainer");
```

Comment: Thank you, my friend. Indeed, this works perfectly. Have a nice week!